# Problem creating a python windows executable with pyinstaller - creates, runs but quits immediately

Tags: python, flask, executable

I have the sample python code below.  I create a windows executable app using PYINSTALLER.  When it runs, it immediately quits.  What should I be doing?

I also tried a basic (default) flask app - I get the same effect.  I don't see any errors - just the window opens and closes immediately.  I have searched all over for solutions - the stackoverflow ar [Python script executable crashes immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48979399/python-script-executable-crashes-immediately) does not help.  I am sure smart people have already solved this.  Please help

```
import sys
import zerorpc


class Api(object):
    def echo(self, text):
        """echo any text"""
        return text


def main():
    addr = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:4242'
    s = zerorpc.Server(Api())
    s.bind(addr)
    print('start running on {}'.format(addr))
    s.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you try running the .exe from `cmd` and post the error here ?

Comment: @Solen'ya - thanks for responding.  I was out the whole day today - and only just got back (after midnight).  When I run this script with python app.py - it runs just fine, but when I make a windows exe  ``` pyinstaller -F app.py``` - the exe gives this error ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zerorpc' .  [292] Failed to execute script app``` . Please help

Comment: Check if pyinstaller can bundle that specific module! Basically converters come with some disadvantages. In this case it can be pyinstaller unable to bind zerorpc to exe! Can be due to platform dependency!

Comment: ```import os
import sys
# from flask import Flask

print('os.getcwd is', os.getcwd())
``` .  this works, but does not if i uncomment out the flask import

Answer (score 0):

So, in my case - when I installed python (3.7.x), pyinstaller was installed with it.  I assumed I could use this(now I know better).  I did not install a separate pyinstaller in my virtual env - but I was using that to build the exe.  This was the source of my problem - bcos, as soon as I did a pip install pyinstaller into my v.env - it worked!!!  I am sure it is obvious to many of you who have been at python for a long time - not so for newcomers

I hope I help somebody who may run into this similar problem.  We continue to learn